# Np uedo levantar el servidor de mongodb en centos 7

Tags: mongodb, centos, centos7, vps

como dice el título no puedo levantar el servidor de mongodb.
Estoy usando CWP7 en Centos 7, si intento levantarlo por el panel de control me dice:

```
**Error**
  La base de datos de Mongo no se puede iniciar.
```

Si lo intento por ssh:

```
  Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
  Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
  connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
  @(connect):2:6
  exception: connect failed
```

El archivo mongod.log muestra lo siguiente:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.863+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.879+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.888+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.888+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.888+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.936+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.936+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":929,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","architecture":"64-bit","host":"digitaldynamo.vps"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.9","gitVersion":"6f7dae919422dcd7f4892c10ff20cdc721ad00e6","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"rhel70","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)","version":"Kernel 3.10.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.937+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1","port":27017},"processManagement":{"fork":true,"pidFilePath":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","timeZoneInfo":"/usr/share/zoneinfo"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongo","journal":{"enabled":true}},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.938+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.938+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":1019}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-07-21T12:36:45.938+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
exiting with code 1
```

Por último el archivo de configuración es el que sigue:

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or,alternatively,
  use the net.bindIpAll setting.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Si necesitan alguna información más solo haganmelo saber, soy nuevo en configurar VPS así que lo mas probable es que sea un error tonto mio.
Desde ya les estoy muy agradecido por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Luego de mucho investigar y probar encontré la solución.
Primero hay que cambiar los permisos del archivo:

```
   /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

a 777.
Luego ejecutar:

```
   chown nongod:mongod /temp/
```

Eso es todo, se reinicia el servidor de mongodb y listo.